# Execute python file in cpp

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, pipe, exec, system-calls

I want to execute a python file in cpp, to make it a process that can communicate with my other child process. But when I use

```cpp
execl("python3", "python3", "python/a1.py");
```

to run the python file, the child process returned instantly, and not a single line in my python file is executed.

But when I try using

```cpp
system("python3 python/a1.py");
```

do to the same thing, it works.

Here is my question:

1. I really want to know why the first way doesn't work

I just don't know why it can not work, because I also use execv to load another cpp executable, and it can work, when it goes to python file, nothing just happens.

update:
delete the irrelevant quesiton, correct the file name

Comment: `execl("python3", "python3", "python/a1.py");` looks like you want to run a program as if the command line was `python3 python3 python/a1.py`. Even ignoring the difference in the name of the python script, that's markedly different from `python3 python/ece650-a1.py` command that does work. Start by discarding one of the `"python3"` parameters in `execl` and see what happens.

Comment: I recommend removing question 2 from this question. Every Question should ask one question, but sometimes a bone will be thrown if the questions are tightly related or the answer to one implies the answers to the others. That's not the case here as there is no relationship between the two questions. In fact the second question seems to be a cmake question and not related to C++ programming.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. `execl` doesn't check `PATH`, so you either need to specify the path to the `python3` binary in the first argument or use `execlp` instead of `execl`.
2. You're missing the `(char *)NULL` sentinel to end the argument list.

Note that user4581301's comment is wrong, and you do in fact need to specify `python3` twice to do the equivalent of `system("python3 python/a1.py");`, because the first one is for the file to execute and the second one is for `argv[0]`.